# How to assign Keyboard Shortcut to run a function in Chrome Extension Manifest v3

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I'm stuck trying to implement the [Action command](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/commands/#action-command) so that a keyboard shortcut will trigger the function inside **background.js**. The current code results in nothing happening when the keyboard shortcut is pressed.

Ideally the keyboard shortcut would trigger the function *reddenPage* inside **background.js**.

I assume some code needs to be placed in **background.js**, I'm just not sure where or what the code should be. Any help is much appreciated!

`Manifest.json`

```
{
  "name": "Page Redder",
  "action": {},
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "version": "0.1",
  "description": "Turns the page red when you click the icon",
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "scripting"
  ],
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "commands": {
    "_execute_action": {
      "suggested_key": {
        "default": "Ctrl+Shift+F",
        "mac": "MacCtrl+Shift+F"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

`background.js`

```
function reddenPage() {
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
}

chrome.action.onClicked.addListener((tab) => {
  chrome.scripting.executeScript({
    target: { tabId: tab.id },
    function: reddenPage
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The `command` api is used to listen and act on keyboard shortcuts.

#### Manifest.json

```json
{
  "name": "My extension",
  ...
  "commands": {
    "run-foo": {
      "suggested_key": {
        "default": "Ctrl+Shift+Y",
        "mac": "Command+Shift+Y"
      },
      "description": "Run \"foo\" on the current page."
    },
    "_execute_action": {
      "suggested_key": {
        "windows": "Ctrl+Shift+Y",
        "mac": "Command+Shift+Y",
        "chromeos": "Ctrl+Shift+U",
        "linux": "Ctrl+Shift+J"
      }
    }
  },
  ...
}
```

A listener can be added to the `background.js` to listen for the command.

#### Background.js

```js
chrome.commands.onCommand.addListener((command) => {
  console.log(`Command: ${command}`);
});
```

[Full Documentation regarding keyboard shortcuts.](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/commands/)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond! I'm familiar with the documentation, but struggling implementing it so they keyboard shortcut triggers the function "reddenPage". Any thoughts on how to do that?

Comment: I think in your case you would use `chrome.scripting.executeScript()` (with the correct arguments) underneath the `chrome.commands.onCommand.addListener` listener.

Answer (score 0):

lejlun's answer is not correct! As the Chrome extension documentation says:

> The _execute_action (Manifest V3), _execute_browser_action (Manifest
> V2), and _execute_page_action (Manifest V2) commands are reserved for
> the action of trigger your action, browser action, or page action
> respectively. These commands do not dispatch command.onCommand events
> like standard commands.

You are correctly using the `action.onClicked` event.

The problem is that in the parameter to `executeScript` you wrote `function` instead of `func`. According to the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/scripting/#runtime-functions), the function call should look like this:

```js
chrome.action.onClicked.addListener((tab) => {
  chrome.scripting.executeScript({
    target: { tabId: tab.id },
    func: reddenPage
  });
});
```

Also, the page you are trying to *redden* might have its background color set as `!important`. In this case, your change of the background color will have no effect as it will be overwritten by the `!important` style. To make sure the background color is applied, you can use `document.body.style.setProperty('background-color', 'red', 'important');`